# Simple gradient issue with OpenGL on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, gradient

i was following the tutorial from raywenderlich [website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture), the gradient seems not to work perfectly, is it only because of the iphone simulator, or is it something else? I can't try myself with an iphone. Here is the image :

[image]

And the code :

```
-(CCSprite *)spriteWithColor:(ccColor4F)bgColor textureSize:(float)textureSize {

    // 1: Create new CCRenderTexture
    CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureSize height:screenSize.height];

    // 2: Call CCRenderTexture:begin
    [rt beginWithClear:bgColor.r g:bgColor.g b:bgColor.b a:bgColor.a];

    // 3: Draw into the texture
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    float gradientAlpha = 0.5;    
    CGPoint vertices[4];
    ccColor4F colors[4];
    int nVertices = 0;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, 0};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, 0);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, gradientAlpha};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, screenSize.height);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, 0};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, screenSize.height);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, gradientAlpha};

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // 4: Call CCRenderTexture:end
    [rt end];

    // 5: Create a new Sprite from the texture
    return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];

}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Nicol Bolas the lines above the gradient

Comment: What lines? Are you talking about the gradient banding?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas yes i was expecting a "smoother" gradient, without these bandings

Comment: This tutorial by Ray Wenderlich isn't about gradiens but stripes - do the gradient have to be build with OpenGL or would another solution be fine?

Comment: @Pfitz i'm trying to use openGl, but what other solutions would you have? I am looking to create a line with random points (still can't do it though), create triangles with those points and fill them with a gradient color.

Comment: Have a look at Quartz: [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1)

Comment: @Pfitz thanks, okay, i found this link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/DrawingModel.html which seems to say that opengl is a good solution for game dev, i don't know, i might continue with open gl for now...